# How to expand a specific div element on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

For an example, as in twitter we click Expand on individual tweets and then it just expands giving links to the individual tweet or showing the image or video and also the time stamp.
And then on next click it just hides the expanded data.

Also how to show the show the mouse hand on hovering over the div rather than the mouse arrow.
Exactly like in twitter.

I hope using jQuery its possible. Can someone give me a sample code for implementing this.
??

Answer (score 0):

you'll want:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $('div').slideToggle();
});
```

Make sure you hide the `$('div')` selector

Answer (score 0):

For expanding an extra section, you are going to want to have two divs. One will have the default information you want to show. The second will contain what you want to expand and show. Then you use something like:

```
$('#expand_button').click(function(){
     $('#second_div').slideToggle();
});
```

For the curser: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp
Use something like:

```
div { cursor: arrow; }
```